# How can i insert large figure in IEEE template

Tags: ieeetran

Please, i have to insert a figure (width 1177, height 437) in IEEE template two columns.
Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{./Panel}
\caption{MY Panel}
\label{fig:Panel}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that the figure is very large, i can't insert it clearly. Have you an idea please about a solution ?

Comment: remove the `[H]` and use `figure*` environment. It will make it a two column figure but don't worry too much about the placement. After the acceptance they will fix it for you.

Comment: i need the option H: here ! how can i set the position of the figure ? i'd like to fix it. Thanks a lot for help. Best Regards.

Comment: You can't without a serious hack. Two column mode is not straightforward to handle.

Answer (score 1):

This works, try changing the width to get image properly aligned within the column.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{./Panel}
\caption{MY Panel}
\label{fig:Panel}
\end{figure}
```

or

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Panel}
\caption{MY Panel}
\label{fig:Panel}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me just the scale reduction does the trick.

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{CDD.PNG}}
    \caption{Types of Infrastructure.}
    \label{CDD}
\end{figure}
```

Does fit in a column my CDD.PNG of size 75.4KB & 2025x1153 pixels