# ieeetran: how to start page with (wide) figure on top?

Tags: ieeetran

I would like to force `ieeetran` to start a new page with a wide (i.e. 2-column) figure on top, and render text below it. So far I've been unable to achieve this behavior in a "deterministic" way, and the only workaround I've found for having wide figures on the top of pages is to move their instantiation back to some previous portions of text code--through a cumbersome trial-and-error process--, but this results in chaos as I end up having seemingly-random instantiations all over my code. Instead, I'd like to keep the figure instantiations within the code of the sections where they belong, but if I do so, it seems impossible to force them to be rendered at the top of the page. How can I achieve this? Thanks, Jorge.

Example:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{Some dummy figures.}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure*}

\section{This text should follow Fig. \ref{fig1}, not precede it!}
\lipsum[1-6]

% Problem happens also after a \clearpage
\clearpage
\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth,height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-c}}
    \caption{Another figure.}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure*}

\section{This text should follow Fig. \ref{fig2}, not precede it!}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `figure*` always appear  on the top **of the next page** where it is inserted. this means, that it cannot be on the first page of the document. to better see this, in your mwe increase number paragraphs of the `\lipsum` and remove `\clearpage`

Comment: I'm surprised to learn this! Maybe it would be possible to redefine/tweak it to insert it in the current page?

Comment: with help help of the package`stfloats` is possible insert it on the bottom of the current page, but not on the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is similar to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329709/how-to-put-figure-at-middle-or-at-desired-position-on-a-page/329777?s=5%7C11.7958#329777), but easier.  Note that a figure without a caption does not show up in the list of figures.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setcaptype}[1]{\def\@captype{#1}}
\makeatother

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}% measuer height of figure
\setcaptype{figure}%
\centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{Some dummy figures.}
    \label{fig1}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{figure}[t]
\rlap{\usebox\tempbox}
\end{figure}
\afterpage{\begin{figure}[t]% next column
\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr \ht\tempbox+\dp\tempbox}
\end{figure}}

\section{This text should follow Fig. \ref{fig1}, not precede it!}
\lipsum[1-6]

% Problem happens also after a \clearpage
\clearpage
\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}% measuer height of figure
\setcaptype{figure}%
\centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth,height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-c}}
    \caption{Another figure.}
    \label{fig2}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{figure}[t]
\rlap{\usebox\tempbox}
\end{figure}
\afterpage{\begin{figure}[t]% next column
\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr \ht\tempbox+\dp\tempbox}
\end{figure}}

\section{This text should follow Fig. \ref{fig2}, not precede it!}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution, John! I'll try to digest it myself (but not now--I have a deadline, and the important thing is that it solves my problem! :) )