# Removing the space in the page before appendix

Tags: spacing, appendix

I am writing a paper in IEEE format, in two columns. I will include some large figures in the appendix, spanning two columns - wide but not long -, because in text placement of the figures spoil the organization of the paper. But, when I create the appendix, after references there is a huge blank space and the appendix goes to the next page. I am including a sample code to show the problem.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
%        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8

\documentclass[conference,10pt]{IEEEtran}
\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
\def\@oddhead{\mbox{}\scriptsize\rightmark \hfil \thepage}%
\def\@evenhead{\scriptsize\thepage \hfil \leftmark\mbox{}}%
\def\@oddfoot{}%
\def\@evenfoot{}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}


\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{balance} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{balance}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[final]{changes}
\definechangesauthor[color=BrickRed]{EE}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}
\makeatletter
\setremarkmarkup{\todo[color=Changes@Color#1!20,size=\scriptsize]{#1: #2}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\note}[2][]{\added[#1,remark={#2}]{}}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts      

\title{\LARGE \bf A long title comes here about lets say whales}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{
Author First\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Second\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Third\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, 
Author Fourth \IEEEauthorrefmark{2} and
Author Fifth \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}A University, City, State\\
Email: \{first, second, third, fifth\}@city.edu}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Another University, City, State\\
Email: fourth@city.edu}}

\begin{document}



\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}

\blindtext

\end{abstract}

\section{Conclusion}
\Blindtext
\Blindtext

\balance
\onecolumn
\section*{Appendix}

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

I changed the content of the paper but am including all the packages I am using in it. As a side note, my large figures are the ones created with \minipage package.[image: This is what I get, please note the large residual space before appendix.]

**EDIT TO THE CODE**

I removed redundant package usage as much as possible for the creation of the problem, I just wanted others to know maybe if one of the packages I used makes that problem.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
%        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8

\documentclass[conference,10pt]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts      

\title{\LARGE \bf A long title comes here about lets say whales}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{
Author First\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Fourth \IEEEauthorrefmark{2} and
Author Fifth \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}A University, City, State\\
Email: \{first, second, third, fifth\}@city.edu}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Another University, City, State\\
Email: fourth@city.edu}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}

\blindtext

\end{abstract}

\section{Conclusion}
\Blindtext
\Blindtext

\balance

\onecolumn

\section*{Appendix}

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: I find some solutions, but they are using 'book' in the documentclass declaration.

Comment: Alas, that always happens when switching between twocolumn and onecolumn.  You could just leave in the gap and let IEEE worry about it.

Comment: Thanks. This is really annoying, I have spent hours to find a solution, I am exceeding the page limit just because of 10 lines, and 2 blank pages (in total)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430/579) shows a very ugly hack that will allow a full width figure or table to occupy the bottom of a two-column page.  Maybe you can make use of it.  However, I'm not sure the IEEE journal editors will be overjoyed.

Comment: I thought of something to try, but your code is full of errors.  Could you go over your preamble and throw out everything you don't really need?

Comment: Barbara, that is great, I will try it.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the trouble, I did not get any errors on my side, but per your request, I deleted some portion and updated the code. I hope it is better now.

Comment: Is the command `\setremarkmarkup` no longer defined in the current version of `changes`? I recently updated my TeX system, and that command gave me an error for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses the command `\shortpage` to switch between `\twocolumn` and `\onecolumn` at a natural page boundary.  It puts the formatted text into a savebox and dumps it all in one go.  Whatever is left at the end of the page is processed using multicols.

`\afterpage` executes at the start of the next page, where `\onecolumn` will not create a new page.  It also saves the remaining text from the previous page into `\AP@partial`.

```
\documentclass[conference,10pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{balance}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newsavebox{\shortpagebox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shortpage}[1]% #1= \twocolumn text to wrap into \onecolumn page
{\par
  \setbox\shortpagebox=\vbox{\strut #1\par}%
  \afterpage{\onecolumn
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \unvbox\AP@partial
    \end{multicols}}%
  \unvbox\shortpagebox
\par}
\makeatother

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts      

\title{\LARGE \bf A long title comes here about lets say whales}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{
Author First\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Second\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Third\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, 
Author Fourth \IEEEauthorrefmark{2} and
Author Fifth \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}A University, City, State\\
Email: \{first, second, third, fifth\}@city.edu}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Another University, City, State\\
Email: fourth@city.edu}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}

\blindtext

\end{abstract}

\section{Conclusion}
\Blindtext
\shortpage{\Blindtext}

\section*{Appendix}

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: I updated the solution so that the entire multicols environment is inside \afterpage.

Comment: That is how I used it `\shortpage{\bibliography{main}}` and it works. That is a great help.