# How to avoid a page break with \newgeometry and \restoregeometry

Tags: geometry

I want what the following code does, but with no page break when `\newgeometry` or `\restoregeometry` are issued. Is that possible?

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]

\newgeometry{verbose,tmargin=8cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}

\lipsum[1-20]

\restoregeometry

\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't.  The flowfram package will allow you to break a page into different sized chunks, but you have to set up the whole page in the preamble.  What you can do is overlap the left and right margins, or preempt the top margin with afterpage.

Comment: you can almost always avoid `\newgeometry` alltogether, you can change the margins just with the standard `quote` environment or a copy that changes the margins by a different amount/

Comment: Thanks! I have just replaced `\restoregeometry` with `\afterpage{\restoregeometry}`, and the geometry is no restored!

Comment: @JohnKormylo I weep if anyone suggests using afterpage in a real document:-)

Comment: you have not stated what is the actual effect that you want to achieve., just  a 6cm space at the top of page 2?

Comment: @David I have a long enumerate spanning several pages, which I want to have a larger top margin (say 4cm) after the second page on.

Comment: so specify the page dimension for the general pages and put `\vspace*{-4cm}` before the list.

Comment: \restoregeometry must use local rather than global assignments.  Sorry, never mind.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - And I thought https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix/477197?r=SearchResults&s=2|24.2599#477197 was one of my best ideas ever.

Comment: @JohnKormylo :-)

Comment: @David Thanks! Your solution works fine!

Comment: it's a solution for the case in the comments but not for the harder case in your example that has three sections, initial, middle with large top margin and end, the vspace* version only really works in the case where you just want a different margin on the first page

Comment: @David True. It must be a hard problem, as I, before asking my question here, searched the web exhaustively and found no solution for many similar questions.

Comment: It's a hard problem in general but almost all actual use cases have simple solutions, so the motivation to tackle the general case is rather small....

Comment: @David Can your solution be adapted to accommodate 2 enumerate lists with different top margins for each enumerate list? That is, 8cm of top margin for the first enumerate list and 5cm of top margin for the second enumerate list.