# How to break a single page mode in a two column article

Tags: tables, longtable, two-column, article

I am writing a two-column style article, using the [A&A package](https://www.aanda.org/doc_journal/instructions/aadoc.pdf). I'm trying to insert a single-column table, that is too large for one page, so I use the `longtable` package.
Because `longtable` has problems with the two-columns article, I have adopted this solution:

```
\onecolumn
\begin{longtable}{ccccccccccc}
*very long table*
\end{longtable}
```

And this solution works well, but on the last table page there is a long white space before the following paragraphs, and I don't want this:

[image]

Is there a way to cut that white space?

Comment: `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` automatically insert a page break

Comment: It might be possible to use \afterpage to put the tail end of the longtable into the title portion of \twocolumn.  I did something similar in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix, albeit for normal text.