# Multiple single-column appendices in a two-column document (IEEEtran)

Tags: two-column, ieeetran

I am using the IEEEtran document i.e., `\documentclass[journal, twoside]{IEEEtran}`, which is a default two-column format. I need to insert multiple single-column appendices, without getting any new page. **Note that these appendices will be spread over multiple pages**. Can anyone let me know how to get this done in latex?

Many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix  Once you are in onecolumn, adding more appedices should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,...]{...}
...
the end of your two column text.
\onecolumn  % switch to one column
\appendix
Code for appendices will be typeset in one column
and so on.
```

In general, when switching between one column and two column mode a new page is started (in some cases this can be useful as when changing the page layout dimensions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already mentioned in my question that I wish to avoid getting a new page. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: @NashJ. Not that I know of unless you use the `multicol` package but I have no idea how that would work with the `IEEEtran` class. You will have to experiment. --- GOM