# Documentclass IEEEtran is not working with glossaries style long

Tags: longtable, glossaries, ieeetran

At the moment I try to add an acronym list into my document with the `IEEEtran` `documentclass`.

Which is working but the spacing between the short and long acronym form is off:

[image]

So i tried to change the `printglossary style` to `style=long`, which gives me an error:

```
Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode.
```

Why do I get this error with `IEEEtran`, but not with other `documentclasses` like `scrartcl`? How can I change the spacing between the short and long acronym form inside the `IEEEtran` `documentclass`?

```
\documentclass[
    conference,
    ]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    ]{biblatex}
\usepackage[
    acronym,
    automake,
    nopostdot,
    toc,
    nomain,
    ]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[
    ]{GASNEV}{GasNEV}{Gasnetzentgeltverordnung}
\newacronym[
    ]{KWK}{KWK}{Kraft-Wärme-Kopplung}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[
    type=\acronymtype,
    nonumberlist,
%   style=long,
    ]

My Acronyms:

\gls{KWK}

\gls{GASNEV}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The glossary style you selected internally relies on longtable which in turn can not be used I solide of a twocolumn documentclass.

Comment: If you really want to use the long form, use \onecolumn.  This can be used in conjuction with \afterpage or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix/477197?r=SearchResults&s=3|15.1575#477197

Comment: Probably you can make use of the `style=super` option which relies on the `supertabular` package instead of the `longtable` package. As far as I remember, `supertabular` can, unlike `longtable` be used in `twocolumn` document classes.