# How to make algorithm2e float?

Tags: floats, algorithm2e

I want to make an algorithm float and I use the algorithm2e package.

However, I can only use `H` for the algorithm.
If I use `htbp`, I will get a `Missing number, treated as zero` error at `\begin{algorithm}`.

Here is the example.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    Test floating.
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
            \begin{algorithm}[htbp]
                \DontPrintSemicolon
                \caption{Test Algorithm}
                \KwIn{An Integer}
                \KwOut{Hash Value}
                \SetKwFunction{FFoo}{Foo}
                \SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{:}{}
                \Fn{\FFoo{$i$}}{
                    \uIf{$i = 0$}{
                        \Return 0\;
                    }
                    \Else{
                        \Return 1\;
                    }
                }
            \end{algorithm}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't put a floating object in a `minipage`. And I also think that `multicols` doesn't like floats.

Comment: The `multicols` is from a template so I cannot modify it, while `minipage` can be removed. Hence, is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: The usual approach is to \end{multicols} add the filoat then start up multicols again.  OTOH, the only real difference between multicol and twocolumn is on the last page (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix/477197?r=SearchResults&s=5|15.5037#477197).