# How to set references to be displayed in one column?

Tags: cross-referencing

The display of my references is like this.
How to make them not evenly displayed on both sides, but displayed in one column?
I used a paper template, and I didn't find the relevant settings. The URL of the template is here.
https://www.microarch.org/micro54/submit/guidelines.php

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix/477197?r=SearchResults&s=2|19.5073#477197

Comment: "Papers must be at most 11 pages, not including references. No page limit for references." Add a couple more, preferably from members of the Steering Committee.:-)

Comment: Comment out (or delete) the instruction `\usepackage[keeplastbox]{flushend}` in `main.tex`?

Answer (score 1):

If your question is related with your **last** reference, with a  first part starting in the page before the last, and a second part fragmented into two columns, in the last page of the document, you should reformulate the question to make it more clear.

I was able to simulate the undesirable behavior you showed: part of  my  last reference (#44) going to the next page and the remaining lines spread over two columns. I didn't like it either.

[image: zz]

The simplest solution I found was tho add some vertical space before the REFERENCES section.

In my case `\vspace*{2\baselineskip}` to push the complete reference #44 to the next page.

This is the time when the author applies some manual touch-ups before delivering the final document.

In your case, I think it will be to try **to save** some vertical space, perhaps by rewriting a few paragraphs or shortening a figure, so that all the references end up on the last page.

[image: xx]

As a guide this is the last part of the modified `main.tex` delivered with the class as example. I collected more references from two sources to fill the two columns.

```
 %%%%%%% -- PAPER CONTENT ENDS -- %%%%%%%%

\vspace*{2\baselineskip} % <<<<<<<<<<< added

%%%%%%%%% -- BIB STYLE AND FILE -- %%%%%%%%
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}
\bibliography{refsx}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

[image: w]

> The `sig-alternate.cls` class has been designed to produce a "tighter"
> document in response to page budget concerns.

As a consequence, the last paragraph of the document will always have two balanced columns.

Comment: thank you. But the reference is about one and a half pages. The references of that half page are displayed in two columns on average. The article is limited to 11 pages, so I will write exactly 11 pages, so there is no way to adjust the paper.