# How to continue at the same page with one column paragraph after balancing two columns?

Tags: two-column, paragraphs, samepage

I have a paragraph text written in two columns, which I balanced equaliy into two columns.
Now I want to continue with one column paragraph at the same page.
However, when I switch to one column, latex skips to next page.
I tried to implement the problem with a very simple code and the image below is showcasing the problem and what I'm intending to. Is there a way of solution to this problem? I would appreciate your suggestions.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,twocolumn, english]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum, babel}
\usepackage[modern, nospread, debug, keeplastbox, checkfloat]{flushend}
\begin{document}
\flushcolsend
\lipsum[1-2]
\twocolumn[{\lipsum[3-4]}]
\end{document}
```

[image: xx]

Comment: Both \onecolumn and \twocolumn start new pages.  OTOH, you can fake it with \afterpage and multicol.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix/477197?r=SearchResults&s=2|19.6792#477197

Comment: @JohnKormylo that worked well. Thank you.

Comment: You might also look at the cuted package.