# How can I make a centered heading for the appendix for an IEEEtran conference format?

Tags: sectioning, appendices, ieeetran, section-titles, center

How can I make a centered heading for the appendix for an IEEEtran conference format? I need the heading to have the same style as the headings that occur within the default IEEEtran conference double-column format.

Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% Packages of your choice, e.g.:
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{import}

% other stuff
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\newcommand{\ts}{\textsuperscript}

\begin{document}

\title{Comparison of Similarity Scoring Algorithms When Applied to the Association for Computing Machinery Dataset}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Name}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Computer Science Division} \\
\textit{Employer}\\
Location \\
\texttt{email}}
}

\maketitle

% abstract
\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Keywords
\end{IEEEkeywords}

% rest of the document
\section{Introduction}
This is part of the IEEEtran double-column format.

% need a single-column section title that appears in the center of the page for the appendix.
```

Comment: Please add a compilable minimal working example which allows users to easily reproduce your document setup.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
You can call the `\onecolumn` latex command to convert to a single-column format. Then you can easily create sections and revert back to the double-column format using the `\twocolumn` command.

```
...
\newpage
\onecolumn
\section*{Appendix}
    % appendix stuff
\twocolumn
    % more double column stuff
```

Comment: You can also use the optional argument of \twocolumn to add a one column heading (which is what \maketitle does).  Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix