# How to set full page geometry while using pages with two columns geometry?

Tags: geometry

I am using this geometry to write:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=9in, top=1in, bottom=0.8in, twocolumn]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\roman*).}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{label=$\circ$}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%\include{frontmatter/colophon}
%\include{fronmatter/frontpiece}
%\include{frontmatter/dedication}
%\include{frontmatter/preface}
\twocolumn
%\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
%\include{mainmatter/Chapter-1}
%\include{mainmatter/Chapter-2}
%\include{mainmatter/Chapter-3}
%\include{mainmatter/Chapter-4}
%\include{mainmatter/Chapter-5}
\include{mainmatter/Chapter-6}
%\include{mainmatter/Chapter-7}
%\include{mainmatter/Chapter-8}
%\include{mainmatter/Chapter-9}
%\include{mainmatter/Chapter-10}
%\include{mainmatter/Chapter-11}
%\include{mainmatter/Chapter-12}
%\include{mainmatter/Chapter-13}
\include{Graphics}
\end{document}
```

I need to use full page instead of splitting it in two columns somewhere in this document. How to set the full page somewhere while using the same geometry with two columns. But where I want to use full page instead of splitting in two columns there should be no splitting of page in two columns.

Comment: unrelated, but do not load `\usepackage{epsfig}`

Comment: just use `\onecolumn` then `\twocolumn` to get back

Comment: There is also `\figure*`, `\table*` and `\twocolumn[...]` to only switch for part of a page.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Can you share  a part of the mentioned for demo

Comment: A lot depends on where you want this to happen.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix/477197?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C20.1982#477197  Also check out the cuted package.