# How to I create double column, continuous table in a 2 column document?

Tags: tables

I tried longtable, it works but gives error. I think longtable do not work on 2 column document. I tried supertabular but it tries to create single column table. Here is my longtable example below.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{ETD observers whose light curves were used in this study.} 
\label{tab:ETDobs} \\

\hline {\textbf{System}} & {\textbf{ETD Number}} & {\textbf{Filter}} & {\textbf{Observer}} & {\textbf{TRESCA Protocol Number}} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline {\textbf{System}} & {\textbf{Filter}} & {\textbf{ETD Number}} & {\textbf{Observer}} & {\textbf{TRESCA Protocol Number}} \\ \hline
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{5}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
GJ 1214 & ETD44 & Clear & Thomas Sauer & 1278597072  \\ 
GJ 1214 & ETD48 & I & Johannes Ohlert & 1281369862  \\ 
GJ 1214 & ETD71 & Clear & ESSEIVA Nicolas & 1368129605  \\ 
GJ 1214 & ETD86 & Clear & Fran Campos & 1436715932  \\ 
GJ 1214 & ETD97 & I & Marc Bretton & 1531068175  \\ 
GJ 1214 & ETD105 & Clear & Paul Benni & 1616843398  \\ 
HAT-P-1 & ETD37 & R & Ramon Naves & 1378191469  \\ 
HAT-P-1 & ETD44 & V & Marc Bretton & 1506648757  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD9 & Clear & Luboš Brát & 1252467945  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD18 & Clear & Samuel Durrance, Stacy Irwin & 1292271351  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD21 & Clear & Luboš Brát & 1317438434  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD36 & R & Mark Salisbury & 1350197834  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD39 & Clear & Alfonso Carreno & 1354463447  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD44 & Clear & Paul Benni & 1380843090  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD71 & R & Ferran Grau Horta & 1419237611  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD85 & Clear & David Molina & 1476120518  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD87 & R &  Wonseok Kang & 1484834873  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD88 & R &  Wonseok Kang & 1484831725  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD99 & V & Yves Jongen & 1544871912  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD100 & Clear & Bruno Fontaine & 1546017209  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD101 & Clear &  Yves Jongen & 1567668774  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD102 & R &  Veli-Pekka Hentunen & 1569003995  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD103 & V & Yves Jongen & 1569911364  \\ 
HAT-P-10 & ETD113 & Clear & Matthieu BACHSCHMIDT & 1638791203  \\ 
HAT-P-13 & ETD39 & R & Ramon Naves & 1296839849  \\ 
HAT-P-13 & ETD82 & Clear & Marc Bretton & 1446972948  \\ 
HAT-P-13 & ETD100 & Clear & Manfred Raetz & 1579296693  \\ 
HAT-P-13 & ETD104 & R & Manfred Raetz & 1585809439  \\ 
HAT-P-13 & ETD107 & R & Yves Jongen & 1612792652  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD10 & R & Ruth ODougherty Sanchez & 1291563452  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD13 & Clear & Stan Shadick & 1318731754  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD15 & Clear & Jaroslav Trnka & 1317463132  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD16 & R & Thomas Sauer & 1317639008  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD2 & Clear & Jaroslav Trnka & 1278846773  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD23 & I & Stan Shadick & 1349233966  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD27 & R & Petri Kehusmaa, Caisey Harlingten & 1351258657  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD31 & R & Mark Salisbury & 1378590453  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD36 & Clear & Stan Shadick & 1383606249  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD37 & Clear & Paul Benni & 1383673356  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD38 & Clear & Anthony Ayiomamitis & 1383875650  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD39 & R & Francesco Scaggiante, Danilo Zardin & 1386236706  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD45 & Clear & Luca Rizzuti & 1440519027  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD46 & Clear & David Molina & 1446965044  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD47 & R & Fran Campos & 1448107877  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD5 & Clear & Martin Vrašťák & 1285498403  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD57 & R & Ramon Naves & 1473584609  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD59 & Clear & Trnka J. & 1477940875  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD6 & Clear & J. Világi, Š. Gajdoš & 1288224520  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD60 & Clear & David Molina & 1479143435  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD61 & I & Kevin B. Alton & 1507651821  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD63 & R & Veli-Pekka Hentunen & 1534770239  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD64 & Clear & Anael Wunsche & 1537205125  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD65 & R & JOSEP GAITAN & 1545555524  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD69 & V & Yves Jongen & 1567852468  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD70 & R & Francesco Scaggiante, Danilo Zardin & 1569339710  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD70 & R & Marco Fiaschi & 1569339710  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD7 & I & Stan Shadick & 1286159180  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD72 & V & Mario Morales & 1571209785  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD73 & V & Truman State Observer & 1583901308  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD76 & Clear & Anael Wunsche & 1596031262  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD78 & R & Yves Jongen & 1599988642  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD79 & R & Yves Jongen & 1602144863  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD80 & V & Snaevarr Gudmundsson & 1605914982  \\ 
HAT-P-16 & ETD9 & Clear & Stan Shadick & 1288134822  \\ 
HAT-P-22 & ETD53 & B & Yves Jongen & 1550908562  \\ 
HAT-P-22 & ETD55 & R & JOSEP GAITAN & 1552034513  \\ 
HAT-P-22 & ETD68 & R & Manfred Raetz & 1586181879  \\ 
HAT-P-22 & ETD78 & I & Manfred Raetz & 1614798234  \\ 
HAT-P-22 & ETD79 & Clear & Matthieu BACHSCHMIDT & 1617521673  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD14 & Clear & Stan Shadick & 1331321038  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD15 & I & Stan Shadick & 1333050479  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD16 & Clear & Juanjo Gonzalez & 1329671594  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD18 & R & Stan Shadick & 1331919572  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD22 & Clear & Stan Shadick & 1358100549  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD26 & I & Giuseppe Marino & 1392576172  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD30 & R & ANDRE Christophe, CLEMENT Jacques & 1420878866  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD30 & R & NOUGAYREDE Jean-Philippe & 1420878866  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD32 & R & Marc Bretton & 1425771388  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD33 & Clear & Martin Zibar & 1425774283  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD39 & R & Francesco Scaggiante, Danilo Zardin & 1516875191  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD41 & Clear & Marc Bretton & 1519263504  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD47 & V & Yves Jongen & 1580746869  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD51 & Clear & Marc Bretton & 1586081207  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD52 & R & Yves Jongen & 1607422166  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD53 & R & Jean-Claude MARIO & 1607859317  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD55 & R & Yves Jongen & 1612549479  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD56 & R & Yves Jongen & 1612791934  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD58 & R &  JOSEP GAITAN & 1613042887  \\ 
HAT-P-30 & ETD59 & R & Anael Wunsche & 1613037601  \\ 
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Comment: To be clear, table needs to span across both columns.

Comment: Note that teh center env does nothing here. Additionally, please always provide a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: supertabular should work, but for either you should provide a small complete document not just a fragment

Comment: When i use supertabular, it creates a table that is splitted to two columns but i need table to be  two column wide. This table is part of a document and i am using a journal's class (two column) file.

Comment: If you show no code it is hard to guess what you did wrong and hard to correct it.  you should be able to make an example with `\usepackage[twocolumn]{article}`

Comment: oh you mean you want the table full width, then you can use longtable or  supertab, just put `\onecolumn` before the table and`\twocolumn` after it (if the journal publisher allows that, they may not.)

Comment: Thanks for your understanding @DavidCarlisle. Your suggestion worked!

Comment: You can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix/477197?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C20.3092#477197 to put the start the longtable in the middle of a page, but you will wind up in onecolumn.  You could use multicols there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Summary

I've tried to the best of my ability and through an attempt at interpreting your question to tackle this with the [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package. I hope this is what you're after. If you wish to tweak this further, please have a look at the `tabularray` [manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/tabularray/0) (especially the "Use Long Tables" section).

## Code

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}  % For the modern tabular typesetting
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}  % For the number alignment

\usepackage{multicol}  % For balanced two columns (also allows for easier abrupt termination of columns)

\usepackage{lipsum}  % For dummy text to fill up the two columns


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{multicols}

\begin{longtblr}[
                    caption={ETD observers whose light curves were used in this study.},
                    label={tab:ETDobs},
                ]{
                    colspec={*{2}{X[c,m,0.85]} X[c,m,0.65] X[c,m,1] X[c,m,1,si={table-format=10.0, table-number-alignment=center}]},
                    width=\textwidth,
                    hlines, vlines,
                    rowhead=1,
                    row{1}={guard, font=\bfseries},
                }
System      & ETD Number    & Filter    & Observer                  & TRESCA Protocol Number \\
GJ 1214     & ETD44         & Clear     & Thomas Sauer              & 1278597072 \\
GJ 1214     & ETD48         & I         & Johannes Ohlert           & 1281369862 \\
GJ 1214     & ETD71         & Clear     & ESSEIVA Nicolas           & 1368129605 \\
GJ 1214     & ETD86         & Clear     & Fran Campos               & 1436715932 \\
GJ 1214     & ETD97         & I         & Marc Bretton              & 1531068175 \\
GJ 1214     & ETD105        & Clear     & Paul Benni                & 1616843398 \\
HAT-P-1     & ETD37         & R         & Ramon Naves               & 1378191469 \\
HAT-P-1     & ETD44         & V         & Marc Bretton              & 1506648757 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD9          & Clear     & Luboš Brát                & 1252467945 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD18         & Clear     & {Samuel Durrance,\\
                                           Stacy Irwin}             & 1292271351 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD21         & Clear     & Luboš Brát                & 1317438434 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD36         & R         & Mark Salisbury            & 1350197834 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD39         & Clear     & Alfonso Carreno           & 1354463447 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD44         & Clear     & Paul Benni                & 1380843090 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD71         & R         & Ferran Grau Horta         & 1419237611 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD85         & Clear     & David Molina              & 1476120518 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD87         & R         & Wonseok Kang              & 1484834873 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD88         & R         & Wonseok Kang              & 1484831725 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD99         & V         & Yves Jongen               & 1544871912 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD100        & Clear     & Bruno Fontaine            & 1546017209 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD101        & Clear     & Yves Jongen               & 1567668774 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD102        & R         & Veli-Pekka Hentunen       & 1569003995 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD103        & V         & Yves Jongen               & 1569911364 \\
HAT-P-10    & ETD113        & Clear     & Matthieu BACHSCHMIDT      & 1638791203 \\
HAT-P-13    & ETD39         & R         & Ramon Naves               & 1296839849 \\
HAT-P-13    & ETD82         & Clear     & Marc Bretton              & 1446972948 \\
HAT-P-13    & ETD100        & Clear     & Manfred Raetz             & 1579296693 \\
HAT-P-13    & ETD104        & R         & Manfred Raetz             & 1585809439 \\
HAT-P-13    & ETD107        & R         & Yves Jongen               & 1612792652 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD10         & R         & Ruth ODougherty Sanchez   & 1291563452 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD13         & Clear     & Stan Shadick              & 1318731754 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD15         & Clear     & Jaroslav Trnka            & 1317463132 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD16         & R         & Thomas Sauer              & 1317639008 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD2          & Clear     & Jaroslav Trnka            & 1278846773 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD23         & I         & Stan Shadick              & 1349233966 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD27         & R         & {Petri Kehusmaa,\\
                                           Caisey Harlingten}       & 1351258657 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD31         & R         & Mark Salisbury            & 1378590453 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD36         & Clear     & Stan Shadick              & 1383606249 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD37         & Clear     & Paul Benni                & 1383673356 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD38         & Clear     & Anthony Ayiomamitis       & 1383875650 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD39         & R         & {Francesco Scaggiante,\\
                                           Danilo Zardin}           & 1386236706 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD45         & Clear     & Luca Rizzuti              & 1440519027 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD46         & Clear     & David Molina              & 1446965044 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD47         & R         & Fran Campos               & 1448107877 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD5          & Clear     & Martin Vrašťák            & 1285498403 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD57         & R         & Ramon Naves               & 1473584609 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD59         & Clear     & Trnka J.                  & 1477940875 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD6          & Clear     & {J. Világi,\\
                                           Š. Gajdoš}               & 1288224520 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD60         & Clear     & David Molina              & 1479143435 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD61         & I         & Kevin B. Alton            & 1507651821 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD63         & R         & Veli-Pekka Hentunen       & 1534770239 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD64         & Clear     & Anael Wunsche             & 1537205125 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD65         & R         & JOSEP GAITAN              & 1545555524 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD69         & V         & Yves Jongen               & 1567852468 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD70         & R         & {Francesco Scaggiante,\\
                                           Danilo Zardin}           & 1569339710 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD70         & R         & Marco Fiaschi             & 1569339710 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD7          & I         & Stan Shadick              & 1286159180 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD72         & V         & Mario Morales             & 1571209785 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD73         & V         & Truman State Observer     & 1583901308 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD76         & Clear     & Anael Wunsche             & 1596031262 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD78         & R         & Yves Jongen               & 1599988642 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD79         & R         & Yves Jongen               & 1602144863 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD80         & V         & Snaevarr Gudmundsson      & 1605914982 \\
HAT-P-16    & ETD9          & Clear     & Stan Shadick              & 1288134822 \\
HAT-P-22    & ETD53         & B         & Yves Jongen               & 1550908562 \\
HAT-P-22    & ETD55         & R         & JOSEP GAITAN              & 1552034513 \\
HAT-P-22    & ETD68         & R         & Manfred Raetz             & 1586181879 \\
HAT-P-22    & ETD78         & I         & Manfred Raetz             & 1614798234 \\
HAT-P-22    & ETD79         & Clear     & Matthieu BACHSCHMIDT      & 1617521673 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD14         & Clear     & Stan Shadick              & 1331321038 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD15         & I         & Stan Shadick              & 1333050479 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD16         & Clear     & Juanjo Gonzalez           & 1329671594 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD18         & R         & Stan Shadick              & 1331919572 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD22         & Clear     & Stan Shadick              & 1358100549 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD26         & I         & Giuseppe Marino           & 1392576172 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD30         & R         & {ANDRE Christophe,\\
                                           CLEMENT Jacques}         & 1420878866 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD30         & R         & NOUGAYREDE Jean-Philippe  & 1420878866 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD32         & R         & Marc Bretton              & 1425771388 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD33         & Clear     & Martin Zibar              & 1425774283 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD39         & R         & {Francesco Scaggiante,\\
                                           Danilo Zardin}           & 1516875191 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD41         & Clear     & Marc Bretton              & 1519263504 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD47         & V         & Yves Jongen               & 1580746869 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD51         & Clear     & Marc Bretton              & 1586081207 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD52         & R         & Yves Jongen               & 1607422166 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD53         & R         & Jean-Claude MARIO         & 1607859317 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD55         & R         & Yves Jongen               & 1612549479 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD56         & R         & Yves Jongen               & 1612791934 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD58         & R         & JOSEP GAITAN              & 1613042887 \\
HAT-P-30    & ETD59         & R         & Anael Wunsche             & 1613037601
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

## Image

[image: All 5 pages of the test document stacked vertically together in one image (200 dpi resolution).]

Comment: Yes! This is what i am loooking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @selcukyalcinkaya Would you mind marking this as the answer then? To respect the site's procedure, please refrain from commenting about a *thank you,* and just mark it as an answer. (Although, I do appreciate the comment.)