# How to insert long table take full width page and span over multiple pages in two column article

Tags: tables, longtable, two-column, supertabular

I was asked to write an article in 2-column format, and I have a large table that contains seven columns and a large number of rows. I need the table to take the entire width of the page, and I also need it to continue to next pages. I tried many solutions, but every solution has a problem. For example, when using the longtable package i forced to convert between two columns and one column, and this causes a problem. When the table ends in the middle of a page, the rest of the page is left blank, and the rest of the article is continue at the beginning of a new page. This is an undesirable thing. I also used tabular*, but the table does not continue to the next page.  Is there anyone who has an ideal solution to this problem or has a sample .tex file that contains the format I want? I attach picture as an illustration of what I want[image] and second picture is the issue of empty space after the end of table[image]

Edit: this is my tex code

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Specify a different language here - english by default
\usepackage{lipsum} % Required to insert dummy text. To be removed otherwise
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xtab,afterpage}
\graphicspath{ {./} }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.55cm}  text
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.75pt} 
\begin{document}
% the content of Article in 2 column mode

\onecolumn
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
  \caption[Short caption]{Long captions for the long table.} \label{tab:long1} \\
  % First head
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Time (s)}} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Triple chosen}} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Other feasible triples}} \\ \hline
  \endfirsthead
  % Standard head
  \multicolumn{3}{c}
  {{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page.}} \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Time (s)}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Triple chosen}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Other feasible triples}} \\ \hline
  \endhead
  % Footnote 
  \hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page...}} \\ \hline
  \endfoot
  % Last footnote
  \hline
  \endlastfoot
  % The table
  col1 & col2 & col3 \\
  col1 & col2 & col3 \\
  col1 & col2 & col3 \\
  ..........................
  col1 & col2 & col3 \\
  col1 & col2 & col3 \\
  col1 & col2 & col3 \\
  col1 & col2 & col3 \\
  
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\twocolumn

%rest of article

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: sorry this my first question here , i edit my question and add snapshot from code

Comment: Never, ever embed a `longtable` environment in a `center` environment.

Comment: Please tell us if the `SelfArx` document class files are available online and, if so, where.

Comment: I downloaded the template for the magazine from their site, and it contains this file `SelfArx` within the project files @Mico

Comment: You wrote, "I downloaded the template for the magazine from their site". *Whose site*? (If you think I have psychic divination powers, I'm afraid I'll have to bitterly disappoint you...)

Comment: No, not like that, but I am new here and I do not know exactly what should be included. I mean that I downloaded it from the magazine’s website itself, that is, from here.
[link](https://ijeee.edu.iq/submitamanuscript/)
Because the file you mentioned is so long, I did not include it here. I apologize for the lack of clarification @Mico

Comment: You can (usually) switch in and out of 2 column mode using \onecolumn and \twocolumn, except that it forces a new page each time.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix/477197?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C20.3329#477197 to start in the middle of a page.  Not sure what to do at the end, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide at least an MWE so that anyone can work around on your problem.

Based on my understanding, you can use `longtblr` option from `tabularray` package to generate the table you want.