One column Figure on last page with eualized double columns
I am preparing a manuscript and need to reduce my page-count. The document class is IEEEtran and the situation is as follows:

I equalized the length of both columns on the last page
I want to add an Appendix B that contains a Figure

The heading of Appendix B should still appear in the double column format. Adding a figure is where I run into trouble. Using figure*, it appears on the next page. It should appear, however, as displayed in this illustration:


Here is a non-functioning example:
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}

\markboth{My Journal}
{Author}

\begin{document}

\title{Manuscript}
\author{Author
\blindtext[1]
}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Interesting subjects
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\blindtext[6]

\appendices

\section{Proofs}
\blindtext[2]
\newpage
\blindtext[2]


\section{Pictures}
\begin{figure*}[b]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=yellow, draw=pink, line width = 2mm] (11.1,5.5) rectangle ++(16,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Interesting figure}
\end{figure*}


\end{document}


please provide an example document, by default latex does not support bottom spanning floats, although packages are available that add that,

Thank you for the swift reply. I added a minimum non-working example.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix


By default LaTeX can not use [b] with figure* so you can use dblfloatfix to add that capability. Then also spanning figures always occur at the earliest on the following page so you need to move the environment early enough in the source that it is seen before the final page.
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix,tikz}

\markboth{My Journal}
{Author}

\begin{document}

\title{Manuscript}
\author{Author
\blindtext[1]
}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Interesting subjects
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\begin{figure*}[b]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=yellow, draw=pink, line width = 2mm] (11.1,5.5) rectangle ++(16,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Interesting figure}
\end{figure*}

\blindtext[6]

\appendices

\section{Proofs}
\blindtext[2]
\newpage

\blindtext[2]


\section{Pictures}


\end{document}


Thank you very much. There is no way, however, to keep the code for that picture where it was and have it be displayed as it now is, right?

@ahi there is always a way (eg you could keep it there but redefine the enviornmemt to essentially be a filecontents that writes the figure out to a file and inputs it earlier on the next run, If you have some automated workflow where it is really hard to change the generated document content that might be a reasonable thing to do, but in a normal hand edited latex file, there is not really any reasonable alternative
