# How to put figure in the middle of double column paper without overlapping?

Tags: floats

I'm writing a `double column` paper and I want to insert a `wide figure`. I've been trying to use `figure*` but it didn't work because I used `IEEE` conference template. The figure overlapped with the text if do `figure*`. Then I tried `strip` and it workd. However, the caption of this figure is too far below and can't be centered. Is there a way that I can move this caption a little bit up and make it look like normal figures?

Here's my code for this:

```
%% Main part of the paper  
\begin{document}  
\title{This is a Test for figure Importing}  
\maketitle  
\thispagestyle{plain}  
\pagestyle{plain}

\section{Introduction}  
\lipsum[1-5]  
\subsection{sub1}  
\lipsum[2-4]  
%1st figure  
\begin{strip}  
\begin{figure}[H]  
\centering  
\captionsetup{justification=centering}  
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{"Fig 5".eps}\\  
\caption{Comparison Results of Picked Methods}  
\label{fig:MethodResults}  
\end{figure}  
\end{strip}  

\subsection{sub2}  
\lipsum[2-4]  

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Can you make your `MWE` as in compilable format? i.e., from `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{...}\begin{document}...\end{document}`

Comment: Please show us small but complete document, which we can test as it is and which will demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Hi guys, I've editted my question by including a complete document. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: @YihanChen that is not a complete self contained document, there is no document class or preamble and we do not have access to the image you use. As a self contained image you can either use `\rule{width}{heigh}` or use one of the images from the `mwe` package (see CTAN). And where does `strip` come from?

Comment: IEEEtran supports figure*.  It does not support figure* using [h] or [H].  No one does.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329709/how-to-put-figure-at-middle-or-at-desired-position-on-a-page

Comment: I used figure* but it makes the figure overlap with the text

Comment: Using figure* put my figure somewhere else. Is it possible that I can use figure* and put my figure exactly the location I want like [H]