# IEEE Graphs Horizontal Alignment

Tags: graphics, ieee-style

I am using [IEEE TVCG LaTeX Template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/ieee-tvcg) and would like to insert multiple images next to each other using the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering

    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{universe} % first figure itself
        \caption{Universe}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{figure} % second figure itself
        \caption{Bar Plot}
    \end{minipage}

\end{figure}
```

However, due to the template, the page is divided into two parts and hence the images are not aligned next to each other in a horizontal manner. How can I use the the following code to align the codes next to each other?

Thanks!

Tried 'figure*' environment:

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{LeNet_300_Accuracy} % first figure itself
        \caption{LeNet 300-100-10 Training \& Testing Accuracy}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{LeNet_300_Loss} % second figure itself
        \caption{LeNet 300-100-10 Training \& Testing Loss}
    \end{minipage}

\end{figure*}
```

But this is not helping as well.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete all document, which reproduce your problem, As already mentioned, for figures which span two columns, you should use environment `figure*` which move figure on the top of the next page from point of its inserting.

Comment: I tried with 'figure*' environment, but it's not helping. Added code to question

Comment: Your code fragment works well in my test document, however, we don't know yours. Please, extent your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `figure*` environment instead to span the figure over both columns.

Comment: However, figure* only support [tp] options, although you might take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329709/how-to-put-figure-at-middle-or-at-desired-position-on-a-page