# How can I insert a picture in the middle of twocolumn doccument?

Tags: two-column, includegraphics

I am working in a Springer template. I want to insert a picture in the middle of the page I mean that I want to deactivate the twocolumn option, add the picture then re-activate the twocolumn again, I tried that following instructions:

```
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{cuted}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \begin{document}


    \twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
    Abstract
    \end{abstract}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]

%text
But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure? On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains. But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure? On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains.But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure? On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in.



%%%%%%picture 
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Pictures/Classification.png}
\caption{Flowchart of Vertical Handover Decision}
\label{Classification}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}

\end{document}
```

But the picture still placed at the left of the page. how to replace the picture in the middle like that picture : [image]

Comment: I do not know if it's possible, but just my 2¢ here: I find these images confusing because I never know *where* to continue reading...

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329709/how-to-put-figure-at-middle-or-at-desired-position-on-a-page

Comment: It's possible, but only with a serious hack.  That is the topic of the question linked by @JohnKormylo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\begin{figure*}` environment

```
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Pictures/Classification.png}
\caption{Flowchart of Vertical Handover Decision}
\label{Classification}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure*}
```

Sorry for no full MWE but as the original post dosn't provide one (at least `\documentclass` is missing; also a link or a definition of the Springer template is missing) I wasn't able to come with one up either.

Note: You don't need the `\begin{@twocolumnfalse}` then.

Comment: If i add (*) after figure the place will be replaced in end of the pdf

Comment: This is simply a thing of how LaTeX positions floats. There are special commands for float placements. Look e.g. [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) You placed your figure at the very end of your text. So LaTeX places it most likely also there.