# How to arrange figure in center of page using full width of page while using {IEEEtran} in LaTex

Tags: graphics, positioning, cuted

I am using Overleaf and used the IEEEtran template to write my paper. I want to show a figure to full page width and in the center of the page. But the two-column template is not allowing me to do this. The Code of my figure is given below. I limited the sizes of images according to one side of the template so please ignore that.
I have tried `figure` and `figure*` both but my figure just shows at one half of the page because of ieeetran template.
The sample of code for testing is given below.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx, array, blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c} 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.097]{Result_SAR.png} & 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{exp_0008_Footprint.png} & 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.097]{exp_0008_polygons_900x900.png}\\ 

\includegraphics[scale = 0.097]{Result_SAR.png} & 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{exp_0009_Footprint.png} & 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.097]{exp_0009_polygons_900x900.png}\\ 

\includegraphics[scale = 0.097]{Result_SAR.png} & 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{exp_0012_Footprint.png} & 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.097]{exp_0012_polygons_900x900.png}\\ 

\includegraphics[scale = 0.097]{Result_SAR.png} & 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{exp_0013_Footprint.png} & 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.097]{exp_0013_polygons_900x900.png}\\ 

\includegraphics[scale = 0.097]{Result_SAR.png} & 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{exp_0018_Footprint.png} & 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.097]{exp_0018_polygons_900x900.png}\\ 

\includegraphics[scale = 0.097]{Result_SAR.png} & 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{exp_0019_Footprint.png} & 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.097]{exp_0019_polygons_900x900.png}\\ 

\includegraphics[scale = 0.097]{Result_SAR.png} & 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{ensembled_footprint.png} & 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.097]{ensembled_polygons_900x900.png}\\ 

\end{tabular}
\caption{\label Experiments Results and Polygons}
\end{figure*} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you add an image of the output you got? This (https://imgur.com/TzsFsTb) is what I get if I use dummy images.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329709/how-to-put-figure-at-middle-or-at-desired-position-on-a-page

Answer (score 2):

You can use the environment  `strip` ( package `cuted`) to insert wide material into the two-column document at the desired location.

Obviously it doesn't support floats, so you have to use `\captionof{figure}{<text>}` to insert the caption (package `caption`).

[image: a]

```
    % !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
    
    \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    
    \usepackage{graphicx, array, blindtext}
    
    \usepackage{kantlipsum} % only for dummy text
    
    \usepackage[format=hang]{caption} % captionof <<<<<
    
    \usepackage{cuted} % wide content <<<<
    
    \begin{document}
    
    1.  \kant[1]
    
    \begin{strip} % start wide material
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c c c} 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-a} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-b} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-c}\\ 
            
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-a} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-b} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-c}\\ 
            
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-a} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-b} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-c}\\ 
            
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-a} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-b} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-c}\\ 
            
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-a} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-b} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-c}\\ 
            
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-a} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-b} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-c}\\ 
            
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-a} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-b} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-c}\\ 
            
        \end{tabular}
        \captionsetup{width=0.8\linewidth}
        \captionof{figure}{ Experiments Results and Polygons Experiments Results and Polygon Experiments Results and Polygon}\label{fig:exp}
    \end{strip} % end wide material
    
    2.  \kant[2]    

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** after follow-up question: long figure does not fit in the page.

[image: c]

The  tabular does not break across pages. Put the figure at the beginning of a new page or split the tabular in two, as the following example.

```
    % !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
    
    \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    
    \usepackage{graphicx, array, blindtext}
    
    \usepackage{kantlipsum} % only for dummy text
    
    \usepackage[format=hang]{caption} % captionof <<<<<
    
    \usepackage{cuted} % wide content <<<<
    
    \begin{document}
    
    1.  \kant[1-4]
    
    \begin{strip} % start wide material
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c c c} 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-a} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-b} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-c}\\ 
            
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-a} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-b} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-c}\\ 
            
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-a} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-b} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-c}\\                
        
            \end{tabular}
            \captionsetup{width=0.8\linewidth}
            \captionof{figure}{(a) Experiments Results and Polygons Experiments Results and Polygon Experiments Results and Polygon \emph{(cont. in next page)} }\label{fig:exp1}
            
            \addtocounter{figure}{-1} %reset counter 
            
            \begin{tabular}{c c c} 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-a}&
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-b} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-c}\\   
                        
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-a} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-b} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-c}\\ 
            
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-a} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-b} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-c}\\ 
            
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-a} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-b} & 
            \includegraphics[scale =0.25]{example-image-c}\\ 
            
        \end{tabular}
        \captionsetup{width=0.8\linewidth}
        \captionof{figure}{(b) Experiments Results and Polygons Experiments Results and Polygon Experiments Results and Polygon}\label{fig:exp2}
    \end{strip} % end wide material
    
    2.  \kant[2-6]  

\end{document}
```

Comment: it worked and the basic purpose is fulfilled. Thanks for your help.
But there is a problem now. My figure is very big when it reaches the bottom of the page the last content of the diagram does not show. Neither the content goes to the next page.
Any suggestion or any piece of code which can solve that

Comment: @Muhammad Salman The tabular does not break across pages. You might divide the single tabular into two or put it starting  a new page.

Comment: @Muhammad Salman Please se the update of the answer showing  one way to deal with long figures.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a lifesaver for beginners like me. 

Comment: @Muhammad Salman Thank you for your feedback! You may accept this answer by clicking the check mark in the top left corner.